# Problem in monogame with DPSF particle generator

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xna, monogame

I'm trying to use [DPSF](http://www.xnaparticles.com/) to generate effects like smoke and fire in 3d for my video game but I am facing problems. I have properly installed MonoGame, in which I have already developed a large part of the game but now that I find myself realizing the effects when I try to use DPSF it gives me this error:

> Errore    CS0012  Il tipo 'Game' è definito in un assembly di cui manca il
> riferimento. Aggiungere un riferimento all'assembly
> 'Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Game, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
> PublicKeyToken=842cf8be1de50553'.

```
class DefaultTexturedQuadParticleSystemTemplate : DefaultTexturedQuadParticleSystem
{
    public DefaultTexturedQuadParticleSystemTemplate(Game cGame) : base(cGame) { }
}
```

The error is given by the base keyword, the references are all there. I don't know what to do to solve the problem. Could someone help me, please?

Answer (score 0):

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/misc/cs0012

> The type 'type' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'assembly'.

The error is telling you it cannot find `Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Game, Version=4.0.0.0`. Check that it is in the output directory of your build.

The XNA Framework redistributable package is downloadable at: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=20914

Comment: this does not solve my problem, I downloaded and installed XNA framework from the link that suggested but inside there are no .dll that solve the problem.

Comment: problem solved i was wrong dll to refer to in the project